# Button Command inside a popupbox, binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, command

I have a button (x:name="MyButton") inside a PopuBox in wpf.

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignRightEdges" 
                         StaysOpen="True"  
                         Padding="0 0 -1 0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Calendar" 
                                         Foreground="{StaticResource PrimaryHueLightBrush}"
                                         Width="20" 
                                         Height="20"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                      </materialDesign:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
                              <Button Content="Ok"
                                      x:Name ="MyButton"
                                      Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                                      Margin="0 5 40 5"
                                      Command="{Binding ClosePopUp}"/>                                    
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

The problem is that when i click the button (MyButton), the command won't work. I think that has to do with the binding. Every button outside the popubox works correctly.

Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT**

The PopupBox is inside a DataTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by replacing `Command="{Binding ClosePopUp}` with `Command="{Binding DataContext.ClosePopUp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`

The datacontext of the button should be equal to its parent.

Comment: How is it when the command is static instead of a dynamic binding ?